# aam-opencv runs failed in FindOpenCV.cmake

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, cmake

I want to run code of aam-opencv   http://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/

In FindOpenCV.cmake,it writes

```
FIND_LIBRARY(OpenCV_CV_LIBRARY
NAMES cv opencv
PATHS ${OpenCV_ROOT_DIR}
PATH_SUFFIXES ${OpenCV_LIBDIR_SUFFIXES} )
```

and

```
IF (OpenCV_${NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR AND OpenCV_${NAME}_LIBRARY)
LIST(APPEND OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_${NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR} )
LIST(APPEND OpenCV_LIBRARIES ${OpenCV_${NAME}_LIBRARY} )
#DBG_MSG("appending for NAME=${NAME} ${OpenCV_${NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR} and ${OpenCV_${NAME}_LIBRARY}" )
ELSE (OpenCV_${NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR AND OpenCV_${NAME}_LIBRARY)
DBG_MSG("OpenCV component NAME=${NAME} not found! "
"\nOpenCV_${NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR=${OpenCV_${NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR} "
"\nOpenCV_${NAME}_LIBRARY=${OpenCV_${NAME}_LIBRARY} ")
SET(OpenCV_FOUND OFF)
ENDIF (OpenCV_${NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR AND OpenCV_${NAME}_LIBRARY)
```

But it can not find OpenCV_CV_LIBRARY such as cv,opencv,CXCORE CVAUX HIGHGUI as there is no cv.so,opencv.so in my opencv lib directory.
Has anyone successfully run it? What should I do?

Comment: What is in your opencv lib directory?

Comment: At first I use /usr/local/opencv, as I failed so change to /usr/local

Comment: @tpg2114 If I do not set opencv's directory, it is /usr/local. Right?

Comment: I mean what files are inside it? You said there's not `cv.so` or `opencv.so`, so what files are there?

Comment: libavcodec.so   libavutil.so          libopencv_features2d.so  libopencv_imgproc.so    libopencv_video.so
libavdevice.so  libopencv_calib3d.so  libopencv_flann.so       libopencv_legacy.so     libpostproc.so
libavfilter.so  libopencv_contrib.so  libopencv_gpu.so         libopencv_ml.so         libswscale.so
libavformat.so  libopencv_core.so     libopencv_highgui.so     libopencv_objdetect.so

Comment: I think there is a  cv.so  in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages